# Corrupted name of installation script-file in custom extension

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, installation, package

I've created custom extension(Magento 1.7.0.2, Ubuntu 14.04), made a package and trying to install it. Everything seems to be ok. 
But instead of file `sql/mycompany_thenameofdevelopedmodule/install-3.1.5.6.php` it creates a directory with the same name (`install-3.1.5.6.php`).

After some investigation I found that if summary path string length is too long, old Magento(1.7.0.2) unpack script will corrupt a file name. For ex.(in my case),

```
/var/www/mystore/public_html/app/code/community/MyCompany/Thenameofdevelopedmodule/sql/mycompany_thenameofdevelopedmodule/install-3.1.5.6.php
```

EDIT: Added error to post

```
2015-07-09T11:43:22+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(/var/www/mystore/public_html/app/code/community/MyCompany/Thenameofdevel‌​opedmodule/sql/mycompany_thenameofdevelopedmodule/install-1.2.1.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/mystore/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php on line 624 Rising of warning error is logical - file became a directory, so it doesn't exist anymore
```

will cause the problem I've described above…

Has anyone faced with this problem and what is the solution except of making the path shorter?

Comment: Can you paste the error that it returns?

Comment: 2015-07-09T11:43:22+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(/var/www/mystore/public_html/app/code/community/MyCompany/Thenameofdevelopedmodule/sql/mycompany_thenameofdevelopedmodule/install-1.2.1.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /var/www/mystore/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php on line 624

Rising of warning error is logical - file became a directory, so it doesn't exist anymore

Answer (score 1):

Maybe conversion fails because your folder does not contain `_setup`.

Check if and how you defined it in your `<resources>` section in your config.xml.

I think it should be
`sql/thenameofdevelopedmodule_setup/install-3.1.5.6.php` instead of `sql/mycompany_thenameofdevelopedmodule/install-3.1.5.6.php`.